# How can I enable input microphone when I select on the combo box

Tags: c#, winforms, speech-recognition

I am making Speech to text application in C# window form with Microsoft Azure. I would like to have a combo box on my form which show the user enable microphone. When I select the enable microphone and press the ok button the microphone will be select as input which I selected. Which I have include in combo box which they would like to use.

How can I implement such a feature?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint waveInGetNumDevs();

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern uint waveInGetDevCaps(uint hwo, ref WAVEOUTCAPS pwoc, uint cbwoc);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public struct WAVEOUTCAPS
        {
            public ushort wMid;
            public ushort wPid;
            public uint vDriverVersion;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
            public string szPname;
            public uint dwFormats;
            public ushort wChannels;
            public ushort wReserved1;
            public uint dwSupport;
        }

        public void FillSoundDevicesInCombobox()
        {
            uint devices = waveInGetNumDevs();
            WAVEOUTCAPS caps = new WAVEOUTCAPS();
            for (uint i = 0; i < devices; i++)
            {
                waveInGetDevCaps(i, ref caps, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(caps));
                CB1.Items.Add(caps.szPname);
            }
        }
      
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillSoundDevicesInCombobox();

            // Only select the device if there is a value to load
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedAudioDevice))
            {
                // find the device, matching on the value, not index
                var item = CB1.Items.Cast<string>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals(Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedAudioDevice));
                // only select the device if we found one that matched the previous selection.
                if (item != null)
                    CB1.SelectedItem = item;
            }

            checkBox1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.Punctuation;
            //CB1.SelectedItem = Properties.Settings.Default.FillSoundDevicesInCombobox;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedAudioDevice = CB1.SelectedItem?.ToString();
            Properties.Settings.Default.Punctuation = checkBox1.Checked;
            //Properties.Settings.Default.FillSoundDevicesInCombobox = CB1.SelectedItem?.ToString();
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use use Lync2013SDK by installing below nuget package:

```
Install-Package Lync2013SDK -Version 15.0.4466.1000
```

Then call below function:

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,  System.EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;
    string selected = (string) ComboBox1.SelectedItem;
    int i = ComboBox1.FindStringExact(selected);

    var manager = LyncClient.GetClient().DeviceManager;
    manager.ActiveAudioDevice = (AudioDevice)manager.AudioDevices[i];   // This is what you want

}
```

Comment: in combo box there is enable microphone is shown i want to add when i select any enable microphone from combo box and then press ok button the select microphone will be available

Comment: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Uc, Version=15.0.4603.1000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.' it was showing error

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio` instead of interop.

Here's an example of a program which starts recording if a volume threshold on a microphone is breached, I just pulled it from a much larger project so it is incomplete but if one can read the code, it should show one how to get started.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Yeti.MMedia;
using Yeti.MMedia.Mp3;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using LoudSoundMonitor;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Security;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.Collections;
 
namespace LoudSoundMonitor
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        Microphone microphone = Microphone.Default;
        byte[] buffer;
        byte[] backBuffer;
        private int minimumThreshold = 759990;
        private int thresholdCount = 0;
        private int thresholdCountMax = 3;
        private int delayStartSeconds = 4;
        private Mp3Writer mp3Writer;
        private const int LSM_NotStarted = 1;
        private const int LSM_Started = 2;
        private const int LSM_Recording = 3;
        private const int LSM_Paused = 4;
        private const char LSM_Client_Transmission_Complete = '\u0004';
        private int LSM_State = LSM_NotStarted;
        private int prev_LSM_State;
        
        private string loudSoundDir = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\LoudSounds\\";
        private string baseDir = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
        private static readonly Regex HttpPostParameterDelimiterRegex = new Regex(@"&", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        private static readonly Regex HttpPostParameterRegex = new Regex(@"^(?<ParameterName>\S+)=(?<ParameterValue>\S*)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
 
       
        private const int ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION = 32;
        private const int ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS = 183;
 
        private object lameMp3EncoderLock = new object();
 void microphone_BufferWrite(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lock (lameMp3EncoderLock)
            {
                if (backBuffer != null)
                {
                    mp3Writer.Write(backBuffer, 0, backBuffer.Length);
                    backBuffer = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    mp3Writer.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
                microphone.GetData(buffer);
 
                if (LSM_State != LSM_Recording)
                {
                    mp3Writer.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    mp3Writer.Close();
                    backBuffer = new byte[buffer.Length * thresholdCountMax];
                    microphone.BufferReady -= new EventHandler<EventArgs>(microphone_BufferWrite);
                    microphone.BufferReady += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(microphone_BufferMonitor);
                }
            }
        }
 
        void microphone_BufferMonitor(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Retrieve audio data
            microphone.GetData(buffer);
 
            // RMS Method
            double rms = 0;
            ushort byte1 = 0;
            ushort byte2 = 0;
            short value = 0;
            int volume = 0;
            rms = (short)(byte1 | (byte2 << 8));
 
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length - 1; i += 2)
            {
                byte1 = buffer[i];
                byte2 = buffer[i + 1];
 
                value = (short)(byte1 | (byte2 << 8));
                rms += Math.Pow(value, 2);
            }
            rms /= (double)(buffer.Length / 2);
            volume = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(rms));
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("buffer.Length" + buffer.Length + " Volume:" + volume);
 
            if ((volume > minimumThreshold))
            {
 
                System.Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, backBuffer, thresholdCount * buffer.Length, buffer.Length);
 
                thresholdCount++;
                if (thresholdCount == thresholdCountMax)
                {
                    thresholdCount = 0;
 
                    button1.Invoke(new System.Action(delegate()
                    {
                        button1.Text = "Recording...Press To Stop";
                        button1.Enabled = true;
                    }));
 
                    String fileName = "LoudSound_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".mp3";
                    if (!Directory.Exists(loudSoundDir))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(loudSoundDir);
                    }
                    lock (lameMp3EncoderLock)
                    {
                        mp3Writer = new Mp3Writer(new FileStream(loudSoundDir + fileName, FileMode.Create), new WaveLib.WaveFormat(microphone.SampleRate, 16, 1));
                    }
                    lock (lockLSM_State)
                    {
                        LSM_State = LSM_Recording;
 
                        microphone.BufferReady -= new EventHandler<EventArgs>(microphone_BufferMonitor);
                        microphone.BufferReady += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(microphone_BufferWrite);
 }
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Threshold exceeded");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("buffer.Length" + buffer.Length + " Volume:" + volume);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            thresholdCount = 0;
        }
    }

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
microphone.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        buffer = new byte[microphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(microphone.BufferDuration)];
        backBuffer = new byte[buffer.Length * thresholdCountMax];

        DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();

        dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
        dt.Tick += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); }
            catch { }
        };
        microphone.BufferReady += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(microphone_BufferMonitor);

        int curInterval = 0;
        System.Threading.Timer delayStart = null;
        delayStart =
            new System.Threading.Timer(
                delegate
                {
                    if (curInterval == delayStartSeconds)
                    {
                        dt.Start();
                        microphone.Start();
                        delayStart.Dispose();
                        button1.Invoke(new System.Action(delegate()
                        {
                            button1.Text = "Monitoring...";
                        }));
                        LSM_State = LSM_Started;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        button1.Invoke(new System.Action(delegate()
                        {
                            button1.Text = "Beginning Monitoring in " + (delayStartSeconds - curInterval) + " seconds";
                        }));
                    }

                    curInterval++;
                }
            );
        this.Load += delegate
        {
            delayStart.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        };
   }
}
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text = "Monitoring...";
        button1.Enabled = false;
        lock (lockLSM_State)
        {
            LSM_State = LSM_Started;
            prev_LSM_State = 0;
            if (microphone.State == MicrophoneState.Stopped)
            {
                microphone.Start();
            }
        }
    }
```